# EF Core 2.1.1 This platform does not support distributed transactions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I use .NET Standart 2.0 and EF Core 2.1.1 and my code looks like this.

```
private async Task<SaveResult>MatchCollection(int invoiceId) 
{
      using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
           var invoice = DataUnit.GetInvoiceOutgoings(invoiceId)
        }
}
```

and on DataUnit class GetInvoiceOutgoings method looks like

```
public Invoice GetInvoiceOutgoings(int invoiceId)
{
        return Context.CollectionInvoiceMatches.AsNoTracking()
                .Include(m => m.InvoiceOutgoing)
                .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == invoiceId);

}
```

I get an "This platform does not support distributed transactions" error when accessing to Context.I know that Ef core 2.1.1 does not support distributed transactions but I do not use distributed transactions.Am I getting this error because of I create a new instance of dbContext on each call? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this problem still occur when you remove `AsNoTracking()`?

Comment: yes I removed and tried without AsNoTracking and the same error still occur

Comment: What happens if you move the transaction scope **inside** `GetInvoiceOutgoings?

Comment: I can't move transaction scope inside GetInvoiceOutgoings because  there are many methods in MatchCollection method which should be in transaction scope also.

Comment: Can you double check to make sure there is no other database call going at the same time? Found this description of the same issue that eventually got resolved by finding a timing issue during debugging: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29633